# jQuery sortable function compatability with ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have rather strange thing happening.

As I know, $.ajax function works with both jQuery and Zepto.js (i've personally tried the latter). I have a ajax function that uploads data to database, and it works fine.

Also, I have a div tag, and inside that div tag i have an ul tag. LI items inside that UL are made sortable and draggable using jQuery.

Both work perfectly seperately. But when they are both in one code, ajax function somewhy doesnt work...

Am I missing something or I made a mistake in code?

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="zepto.js"></script>

<script>
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'update.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: {
                souls:souls,
                bones:bones,
                xp:  $('#xp').val(),
                xp_max: $('#xp').attr('max'),
                hp:  $('#lifes').val(),
                hp_max: $('#lifes').attr('max'),
                level:$('#level').attr('innerHTML'),
                quest:quest,
                is_completed:is_completed
            }
        });
    } ,1000)
    </script>
```

other functions:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>


  $(function() {
      $( "#li" ).draggable({ revert: true });

    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();

    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

    $( "#inventory" ).draggable();


  });

</script>
```

P.S i've tried every placement of the code in case one of them doesnt work, still no result

Comment: Provide full code with HTML or better create a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RKWyV/  i excluded all the unecessary code, it has no impact at all

Comment: do you get any error in console?

Comment: You have invalid HTML. You assigned same ID to all "li". Change that and then try.

Comment: And try adding $('#sortable').sortable('refresh') in your ajax callback function

Comment: Whats wrong with that i added the same id?

Comment: Read here : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really

Comment: doesnt work either...

Comment: when i look in console, it sends a XMLhttprequest, it posts, but it isnt stored in database somewhy. Update.php is totally fine, works when there is only ajax function without sortable

Comment: do you have a link for your code? Is it available online?

Comment: www.greenis.lt/the_cave.php

Comment: You have error in your code. Look into the console, it says "is_completed" undefined. Thats the reason your ajax is breaking.

Comment: if you signed in with an new account, which you can create on greenis.lt page, or admin/admin, youll see that this error will be gone

Answer (score 0):

I saw your source code in the browser and since you have html4.1, so here is something you need to correct:

- Add `type="text/javascript"` in your script tags. Without these, there will be errors.
- Remove same Id from elements. Rather add classes instead of giving same Id.
- Try to use your complete code in a single script tag rather than defining multiple tags.
- Look into your console, there are some errors which you need to fix.

Try these changes.

Comment: still nothing changed